# jQuery through NuGet on MVC 4 producing an unexpected URL path

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget

I am working on a new MVC project that is making use of Bootstrap v3.

Through NuGet, I got the latest version of jQuery by doing:

> Install-Package jQuery

And then I dragged the jQuery (tried minified and un-minified) onto the page like so:

```
    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/easing.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/ddlevelsmenu.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/flexslider.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/custom.js"></script>

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

    </body>
</html>
```

When I run my application, I get the following weird path for jQuery and I can't figure out why!

[image: jQuery path error]

Comment: Are you sure you're using MVC4?  Was this an upgraded project from MVC3?  FYI, you shouldn't use jQuery 2.x unless you're willing to give up IE8 and earlier compatibility.  You need to use jQuery 1.9.x branch until IE8 is fully deprecated.

Comment: No way! Thanks very much I had no idea that the new jQuery did not support IE8. As for MVC4, I'm pretty sure I am, but how can I confirm?

Comment: Check your Web.config in the Views directory, and look for the version numbers of the razor assemblies.  You should see System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35

Comment: jQuery 1.9.x and 2.x are functionally identical.  They are kept in sync, but 1.9.x still has support for IE versions less than IE9, while 2.x has removed legacy browser support.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The path is invalid ".../home/~/Scripts/...", it must be ".../Scripts/..."

Change the code with that :

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/easing.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/ddlevelsmenu.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/flexslider.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/custom.js"></script>
```

Or if you want an absolute path :

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/easing.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ddlevelsmenu.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/flexslider.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.prettyPhoto.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/custom.js")"></script>
```

Comment: That should not be required.  Razor v2 has full support for root based rendering without using Url.Content.  http://vibrantcode.com/blog/2012/4/10/whats-new-in-razor-v2.html/